# printing a periodical series of a number in C

Tags: c, recursion, series

Given a Periodical Series of numbers 
Example X=3

the Periodical Series of x=3 must look like  this

```
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3 
3 1 1 
3 1 2
3 1 3
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
```

Wanted: to write a program in C to print this series 
and given : Assume maximum value of x can be 10

I tried to start with ideas.. but all failed.. 
Please HELP . thanks :)

Comment: I had a bunch of ideas to help you, but all failed. Sorry.  Hard to tell the difference between this and doing nothing, don't you agree?

Comment: Why don't `1 2 1`, `1 2 2` etc. appear?

Comment: ops sorry i forgot it .. edited

Comment: For x = 2, should the output be 11 12 21 22 or 111 112 121 122 211 212 221 222?

Comment: for x=2 .. 11 12 21 22

Comment: and my idea is (According to x=3) : to split the the printing process by 3 parts –
1.)the MSB column changes x^1 times
2.)the middle column changes x^2 times
3.)the LSB column changes x^3 times 

and on and on ..
and i think it should be done by recursion .. but i simply dont know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int printSeries(int list[], int max, int level){
    if(level == max){
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<max;++i)
            printf("%d ", list[i]);
        printf("\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(list[level]<=max){
        list[level]+=printSeries(list, max, level+1);
    }
    list[level] = 1;

    return 1;
}

void printSeriesStart(int x){
    int i, *list = malloc(x*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<x;++i){
        list[i]=1;
    }
    printSeries(list, x, 0);
    free(list);
}

int main(void){
    int X = 3;
    printSeriesStart(X);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @OausimDjango It count up repeatedly from the left-most.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def yourFunction(n, x):
    recursiveFunction(n, x, 0, [0]*n)

def recursiveFunction(depth, breadth, currentDepth, indexes):
    if currentDepth >= depth:
        print indexes
    else:
        for indexes[currentDepth] in range(0, breadth):
             recursiveFunction(depth, breadth, currentDepth + 1, indexes)
```

Comment: @OausimDjango No, that's your job.

Comment: I sat down and tried to code this in my own ham-fisted way. Then I saw your code, started crying and went here: http://www.bkcareers.com/

Comment: but i dont understand ur code .. how i can convert it to C ??
i only know C ..
please help .. thank u

Comment: @OausimDjango If you can't understand it, I'd recommend actually learning at least one programming language, at least to start with.  You clearly don't know even C.

Comment: @AJMansfield well its my first year as software engineer .. and they teach us only C ..

Comment: @AJMansfield can u please convert it to C ? or atleast tell me in what language u wrote

Comment: @OausimDjango It's in python.